# Why is my SOAP envelope empty?

Tags: c#, php, soap

So I'm trying to call a webservice with PHP and SOAP, but it doesn't seem to be doing it correctly and I can't figure out why. Here is the PHP:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
$params->param1 = "satsys";
$params->param2 = "0A259772-983C-4EFB-834E-6184F8E9F4E7";
$params->param3 = null;
$response = $client->SetHardwareProfile($params);
var_dump($response);
echo "Last Request: ".$client->__getLastRequest();
echo "Last Response: ".$client->__getLastResponse();
```

And here is the Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ValidateLicenseKeyResponse ValidateLicenseKey(ValidateLicenseKey $parameters)
    [1] => CreateProviderResponse CreateProvider(CreateProvider $parameters)
    [2] => SetHardwareProfileResponse SetHardwareProfile(SetHardwareProfile $parameters)
    [3] => UpdateCurrentVersionResponse UpdateCurrentVersion(UpdateCurrentVersion $parameters)
    [4] => SoftwareUpdateAvailableResponse SoftwareUpdateAvailable(SoftwareUpdateAvailable $parameters)
    [5] => GetSoftwareUpdateResponse GetSoftwareUpdate(GetSoftwareUpdate $parameters)
)
object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["SetHardwareProfileResult"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Last Request:-->
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:SetHardwareProfile/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<!--Last Response:-->
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<SetHardwareProfileResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<SetHardwareProfileResult>false</SetHardwareProfileResult>
</SetHardwareProfileResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Now from what I have read, it's that request that's a problem, because instead of looking like that, it **should** look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:SetHardwareProfile>
    <customerId xsi:type="xsd:string">satsys</customerId>
    <providerGuid xsi:type="xsd:string">0A259772-983C-4EFB-834E-6184F8E9F4E7</providerGuid>
    <other xsi:type="xsd:string"></other>
</ns1:SetHardwareProfile>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is the service contract, for good measure (written in C#):

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ProviderSync
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IProviderSync
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool SetHardwareProfile(String customerId, String providerGuid, List<Device> hardware);
    }
}
```

Comment: Being a part-time PHP developer (and a full-time .NET developer), I once had large issues until I was able to successfully consume a SOAP service in PHP. I blogged about the solution, [here is a Google translation of the original German posting](http://bit.ly/t9XdTI), maybe it helps you a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem is that with SOAP, unlike with other languages, the parameters have to have their exact names. So the above chunk of PHP code should actually read like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
$params->customerId = "satsys";
$params->providerGuid = "0A259772-983C-4EFB-834E-6184F8E9F4E7";
$params->hardware = null;
$response = $client->SetHardwareProfile($params);
var_dump($response);
echo "Last Request: ".$client->__getLastRequest();
echo "Last Response: ".$client->__getLastResponse();
```

Because they're declared by the service contract as:

```
bool SetHardwareProfile(String customerId, String providerGuid, List<Device> hardware);
```

I am not sure why exactly this is the case, or if this is the case in all forms of SOAP calls, but that change fixed this problem for me.